# How do I use Deserialised JSON Data In VB.Net?

Tags: json, vb.net, class, deserialization

I am trying to access data which I think I have successfully deserialized from a JSON file in vb.net.

My program currently reads data into a string from a JSON file. I have been researching how to deserialize the JSON data into a class structure and used a visual studio feature to create the class structure for me.

My question is how do I access this data after it has been deserialized? I have looked through hundreds of pages of forums and stack overflow posts to no avail.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{
  "total": 389097,
  "offset": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "entity": "Play",
      "arid": "mpdwyOB32n",
      "played_time": "2020-02-21T06:21:26+0000",
      "service_id": "triplej",
      "recording": {
        "entity": "Recording",
        "arid": "mtNYq18DdY",
        "title": "Supalonely",
        "metadata": null,
        "description": null,
        "duration": 219,
        "artists": [
          {
            "entity": "Artist",
            "arid": "ma35vZnl5B",
            "name": "Benee",
            "artwork": [],
            "links": [
              {
                "entity": "Link",
                "arid": "mlb5b4r7A0",
                "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/artist/c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                "id_component": "c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                "title": "MusicBrainz artist",
                "mini_synopsis": null,
                "short_synopsis": null,
                "medium_synopsis": null,
                "type": "service",
                "provider": "musicbrainz",
                "external": true
              }
            ],
            "is_australian": null,
            "type": "primary",
            "role": null
          }
        ],
        "releases": [
          {
            "entity": "Release",
            "arid": "mr45LNQePX",
            "title": "Stella & Steve",
            "format": "EP",
            "artwork": [],
            "links": [
              {
                "entity": "Link",
                "arid": "mlV0JZbO20",
                "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/release-group/9d0271c7-6448-4cbf-a335-0221e34a73ae",
                "id_component": "9d0271c7-6448-4cbf-a335-0221e34a73ae",
                "title": "MusicBrainz release-group",
                "mini_synopsis": null,
                "short_synopsis": null,
                "medium_synopsis": null,
                "type": "service",
                "provider": "musicbrainz",
                "external": true
              }
            ],
            "artists": [
              {
                "entity": "Artist",
                "arid": "ma35vZnl5B",
                "name": "Benee",
                "artwork": [],
                "links": [
                  {
                    "entity": "Link",
                    "arid": "mlb5b4r7A0",
                    "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/artist/c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                    "id_component": "c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                    "title": "MusicBrainz artist",
                    "mini_synopsis": null,
                    "short_synopsis": null,
                    "medium_synopsis": null,
                    "type": "service",
                    "provider": "musicbrainz",
                    "external": true
                  }
                ],
                "is_australian": null,
                "type": "primary",
                "role": null
              }
            ],
            "record_label": null,
            "release_year": null,
            "release_album_id": null
          }
        ],
        "artwork": [],
        "links": [
          {
            "entity": "Link",
            "arid": "mlwkZWz960",
            "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/recording/2772cd61-892c-47ab-bc0e-1ca775ebe6f4",
            "id_component": "2772cd61-892c-47ab-bc0e-1ca775ebe6f4",
            "title": "MusicBrainz recording",
            "mini_synopsis": null,
            "short_synopsis": null,
            "medium_synopsis": null,
            "type": "service",
            "provider": "musicbrainz",
            "external": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "release": {
        "entity": "Release",
        "arid": "mr45LNQePX",
        "title": "Stella & Steve",
        "format": "EP",
        "artwork": [],
        "links": [
          {
            "entity": "Link",
            "arid": "mlV0JZbO20",
            "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/release-group/9d0271c7-6448-4cbf-a335-0221e34a73ae",
            "id_component": "9d0271c7-6448-4cbf-a335-0221e34a73ae",
            "title": "MusicBrainz release-group",
            "mini_synopsis": null,
            "short_synopsis": null,
            "medium_synopsis": null,
            "type": "service",
            "provider": "musicbrainz",
            "external": true
          }
        ],
        "artists": [
          {
            "entity": "Artist",
            "arid": "ma35vZnl5B",
            "name": "Benee",
            "artwork": [],
            "links": [
              {
                "entity": "Link",
                "arid": "mlb5b4r7A0",
                "url": "http://musicbrainz.org/artist/c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                "id_component": "c352c56b-a610-4fc4-884c-704547ef30f5",
                "title": "MusicBrainz artist",
                "mini_synopsis": null,
                "short_synopsis": null,
                "medium_synopsis": null,
                "type": "service",
                "provider": "musicbrainz",
                "external": true
              }
            ],
            "is_australian": null,
            "type": "primary",
            "role": null
          }
        ],
        "record_label": null,
        "release_year": null,
        "release_album_id": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the class structure Visual Studio Generated:

```
Public Class JSON_Class

    Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property total As Integer
        Public Property offset As Integer
        Public Property items() As Item
    End Class

    Public Class Item
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property played_time As Date
        Public Property service_id As String
        Public Property recording As Recording
        Public Property release As Release1
    End Class

    Public Class Recording
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property metadata As Object
        Public Property description As Object
        Public Property duration As Integer
        Public Property artists() As Artist
        Public Property releases() As Release
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Artist
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
        Public Property is_australian As Object
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property role As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Release
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property format As String
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
        Public Property artists() As Artist1
        Public Property record_label As Object
        Public Property release_year As Object
        Public Property release_album_id As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Artist1
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
        Public Property is_australian As Object
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property role As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Release1
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property format As String
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
        Public Property artists() As Artist2
        Public Property record_label As Object
        Public Property release_year As Object
        Public Property release_album_id As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Artist2
        Public Property entity As String
        Public Property arid As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property artwork() As Object
        Public Property links() As Object
        Public Property is_australian As Object
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property role As Object
    End Class

End Class
```

I deserialize my data using this line: (Where JSON_Class is the class structure and New_JSON_Content is the raw JSON)

```
Dim JSON_Wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Class)(New_JSON_Content)
```

What would be my next step if say I wanted to access any one specific variable from the populated class structure? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the dot operator and access the properties like JSON_Wrapper.items(0).Played_time

Comment: Thank you for your response @User965207! I tried playing around with your suggestion however that simply doesn't work for me, if that is how I should be accessing the data then it makes me think I am not deserializing the data correctly? To clarify why it doesn't work the `.items(0)` does not reference anything in my project.

Comment: you can add the JSON_Wrapper  to watch window and check whether all the properties are getting populated or not

Comment: Thank you that's a great suggestion, I have edited my comment above also.

Comment: Looking at the JSON , i dont think JSON_Class is required . Deserialize directly to RootObject class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't see any data is that `JSON_Class`, the class you are deserializing to, contains no members. The code works; it's doing exactly what you're telling it to - create an instance of `JSON_Class` - which contains nothing - from this JSON string. JSON tokens which don't match anything in the deserialization type are ignored, which in this case is everything.

To make this work, deserialize to `JSON_Class.Rootobject` instead. You also don't need to nest your deserialization classes in a containing class.